# BigQuery: SELECT AS STRUCT doesn't named struct fields as expected

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've defined the following UDF to convert a string to a list of word counts:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_bow_vector(document STRING) RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, INT>> AS ((
  SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT word AS word, COUNT(1) AS freq
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(document, r'[\w_]+')) AS word
    GROUP BY word
    ORDER BY freq DESC
  )
));
```

This UDF mostly works as expected: it turns a string into an array of STRUCTs, where each struct contains a word and a count.  However the field of the struct are not named `word` and `freq` as expected.  Instead they're given the anonymous field names: `_field_1` and `_field_2`.

I've got two questions:

1. How can I name the fields of the struct?
2. If I dont' name the fields of the struct, how do I access them anyway?  When I try using `_field_1` I get the following error `Field name _field_1 does not exist in STRUCT<STRING, INT64>`

Comment: Ah, I found one way to work around this: if I take the return type out of the UDF signature, this problem goes away and the fields are named as desired.  Is it a bug that a UDF can't have named fields if I specify the return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below instead

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION get_bow_vector(document STRING) 
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<word STRING, freq INT>> AS ((
  SELECT
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT word AS word, COUNT(1) AS freq
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(document, r'[\w_]+')) AS word
    GROUP BY word
    ORDER BY freq DESC
  )
));
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that field names are part of the return type -- seems unexpected.

Comment: in case of struct  - this makes total sense to  me :o)